# The View Model is passing NULL in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005. I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method. I have a view 'Index' that contain a link to another view 'Update'. The problem that in debugging, the value of view is NULL.

The view is populated by a controller which the name is ProfileGa.

this a part of the code of the controller ProfileGa :

```
public ActionResult Update(string id)
{
    FlowViewModel flv = db.FlowViewModels.Find(id);
    return View(flv);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(FlowViewModel model)
{
    Console.WriteLine("" + model.Nbr_Passage);

        Gamme G = new Gamme();
        ListG.Remove(G);
        db.Gammes.Remove(G); 
        G.ID_Gamme = model.SelectedProfile_Ga;
        G.ID_Poste = model.SelectedPoste;
        G.Last_Posts = model.PostePrecedentSelected;
        G.Next_Posts = model.PosteSuivantSelected;
        G.Nbr_Passage = int.Parse(model.Nbr_Passage);
        G.Position = int.Parse(model.Position);
        ListG.Add(G);
        db.Gammes.Add(G);
        db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

When I put a breakpoint on the line :

```
FlowViewModel flv = db.FlowViewModels.Find(id);
```

The value of flv is NULL. Maybe there's no record with the specified id in the database.

I can't go deep on the methode Find because the code of this methode is predefined (I didn't write it). It is a methode of DbSet.

The same code is working with others views but only this.

I think the problem depends on the ID (ID_Gamme) which is a DropDownList not like the others (TextBox).

This a part of the code of the view Index which contain the link for the view Update :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication2.Models.FlowViewModel>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Helpers" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Index
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<table>

<% foreach (var item in Model.GaItems) { %>
    <tr>
         <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID_Gamme) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID_Poste) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nbr_Passage) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Position) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Last_Posts) %>
        </td>
         <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Next_Posts) %>
        </td>
        <td>    
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Modifier", "Update", new { id=item.ID_Gamme }) %>     
        </td>
    </tr>
<% } %>

</table>

</asp:Content>
```

and this is the code of the model FlowViewModel :

```
public class FlowViewModel
{    
    [Key]
    public string IDv { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public SelectList PostesItems { get; set; }
    public List<Profile_Ga> Profile_GaItems { get; set; }
    public List<Gamme> GaItems { get; set; }
    public string SelectedProfile_Ga { get; set; }
    public string SelectedPoste { get; set; }  
    public string PostePrecedentSelected { get; set; } 
    public string PosteSuivantSelected { get; set; }    
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string  Nbr_Passage { get; set; }    
    public List<Gamme> ListG = new List<Gamme>();    
}
```

A part of Gestion.ascx:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Anouar")) { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset class="parametrage">
        <legend>Gestion de Gamme</legend>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Poste :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedPoste, Model.PostesItems)%></div>

        <div><%:Html.Label("Nombre de Passage :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Nbr_Passage)%></div><div class="editor-field"> <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nbr_Passage)%></div>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Position :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Position)%></div>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Poste Précédent :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PostePrecedentSelected, Model.PostesItems)%></div>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Poste Suivant :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PosteSuivantSelected, Model.PostesItems)%></div>

        <div><input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" id="btnSave"  /></div>
    </fieldset>
...
```

Comment: Did yo uput a breakpoint ON `FlowViewModel flv = db.FlowViewModels.Find(id);` or the line after it, because if you put it on that line, it will be null because that line hasn't assigned it yet

Comment: Hello Anouar, I've helped on a few questions so I thought that FlowViewModel is a ViewModel and not an Entity in the database unless you have made it into a table in the database but that wouldn't make a lot of sense? Is it a table in the database? If not how are you trying to find it in the DB? Plus, as Colm points out see what value is AFTER that call when the value should be set.

Comment: Does `id` have the expected value when you debug it?  If the problem is that `.Find()` isn't finding it, then it sounds like the problem isn't in any of the code posted but instead in the data access.  Perhaps the record you're looking for isn't there?  Are you looking in the correct entities?

Comment: Hello Guys ! Welcome back ! I missed you :p,,,,For the problem of breakpoint, it's always NULL also when i change the line or i use F10.
@Belogix  FlowViewModel is not a table,,,so you have right,,the problem depends on the id

Comment: @David i think it is because FlowViewModel is not a table in my base

Comment: As I thought... So, what / why are you trying to `Find` using the ID?

Comment: @anouar you should put your code on github if you can, it'll make it easier if you need anyone else to figure out future problems.

Comment: @ColmPrunty sure I will try to put it now

Comment: @anouar cool, email me the link when you get it

Answer (score 6):

The issue is because `FlowViewModel` is not an entity in the database but instead a **ViewModel**. Therefore when you try and query the database for `FlowViewModel.Find...` it has nothing to return as it does not map to a database table.

You are probably wanting to get various information from the other tables such as `Gamme` (that you are writing back to). You should populate the `FlowViewModel` from the other database entities and then pass into the View.

So, you want to populate from `Profile_GaItems` and `Gammes` database entities do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Update(string id)
{
    FlowViewModel flv = new FlowViewModel();
    flv.Profile_GaItems = db.Profile_GaItems.ToList();
    flv.GaItems  = db.Gammes.ToList();
    return View(flv);
}
```

Comment: thx,,,with that flv is not null any more but there is an exception :
There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'SelectedPoste'.
Hold On,,,I will put the code of the view Gestion in my edit

Comment: What type (`Inherts="..."`) is your Gestion view?

Comment: It's a partial view (ascx) taking a FlowViewModel, if it hasn't changed from last week.

Comment: <%@  Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MvcApplication2.Models.FlowViewModel>" %>

Comment: @ColmPrunty yes it hasn't changed,,,lol and that github made me crazy lol

Comment: Okay, the error suggests there is something wrong with the view (i.e. it is wrong type or the DropDownList is wrong. I would start another question rather than asking too many questions in one place and confusing matters.

Comment: @anouar - Has this helped? Have you asked another question? Did this answer the specific issue you were having? Any luck?

Comment: @Belogix not yet my friend !

Comment: @Belogix please can you take a look at this problem :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729935/how-to-show-a-list-of-checkbox-according-to-a-dropdownlist-in-asp-mvc-and-entity/16729998#16729998